# How to run sum of a buffer?

Tags: emacs, elisp

So, from my log file, I processed some string and finally got this result in, let's say buffer name "*1*"

```
12
23
34
45
```

How can I get a sum of a given buffer?

```
(defun sum-of-buffer (buf)
  (interactive "bBuffer Name: ")
   ....
  (message "%i" sum))
```

Or is there a convenient function combination?

Answer (score 5):

How about using `calc` -- select the region in the shape of a rectangle -- and type:  `C-u C-x * :`

Alternatively, how about?:

```
(let ((sum 0))
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+" nil t)
      (setq sum (+ sum (string-to-number (match-string 0))))))
  sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Unix machine, `C-x h M-|` and then `awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'`.